# Two actions in the loop body

Tags: formatting

Help me please, how I can write two action in the body of the cycle "for"?

For example, if I need to write Print[] and Append[] at each iteration.

Comment: try `Print[...];Append[...]`? (See [CompoundExpression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompoundExpression.html) in the docs.)

Comment: @kglr, thank you!

Comment: @GThompson but also [don't use For](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica). It's slower, more work, and buggier than the many, many more powerful alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CompoundExpression (;)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html) (expressions separated by `;`) in any argument of `For`:

```
For[i = 0; a = {}, i < 4, i++, Print[i]; AppendTo[a, i]]
```

[image]